# Create list from atoms in the knowledge base

Tags: prolog

I want to make a list from the atoms inside these predicates:

```
country(italy, 30, 40).
country(spain, 10, 30).
```

and then generate:

```
L = [italy, spain]
```

is it possible?

Comment: `findall(C, country(C, _, _), L)`?

Comment: Perfect, thats what i was looking for!! thanks